# Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.Globalization.dll

Tags: c#

I have a C# VS2010 on Win7 application which I can deploy and run on other Win7 computers with .net 4.5

When installing and running the same application on a WinXP, after seemingly successful installation I get an error message "Application Validation did not succeed".

in the error details I can see the problem to be "Strong name signature not valid for this assembly System.Globalization.dll.".
I do include the System.Globalization.dll in the build, and, as I mentioned, it runs OK on Win7.

I goggled and found several relevant references to the problem, but non of them seems to solve it for me.

Observations:
The WinXP computer runs .NET 3.5 (the ultimate for WinXP?).
The WinXP  System.Globalization.dll is a 22K Binary, while the Win7 (VS2010) is a 10K HTML (Is this of any significance, anyhow?)

Any new idea will be welcome!

Comment: which is target framework of your application ?

Comment: Thanks to your comment, and to be on the safe side, I made my target framework to 4.0.  
This is the WinXP target machines FW, and to the best of my knowledge this is also as far as WinXP can go).
Unfortunately, I still get the same error.